# Remove the default confirmation popup while closing the browser using onbeforeunload method

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have one listener in my web app which is not invoke while closing the browser but its invoke while shutting down the server and logging out from application.
      Now its happening while using the below code in jsp page but one default conformation is popping while closing the browser. I am trying to avoid the same while closing the browser. I have used below methods event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();
            Please find the below code snippet I have used.

```
var check=false; 

function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    }
    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
    }
}

addEvent(document, "mouseout", function(e) {
    e = e ? e : window.event;
    var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
    if (!from || from.nodeName == "HTML") {
         check=true;
    }
});

window.onmousemove = function (event) {
  check=false;  
}

window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
  if (check) {
   $.ajax({
        url: "<html:rewrite page="/"/>ClientSelectAction.do?method=invalidateSession", 
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        timeout: 60000,
        //async: false
        error: function() {
            console.log("abcd ");
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log("success "+data);
        }
    }); 
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

   }
}

</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute your logic on the onbeforeunload function and then, set the onunload function to null.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
//do your stuffs
window.onbeforeunload = function(event){
    //do your stuffs
}
window.onunload = null;
}
</script>
<body>
</html>
```